# executeBatch() performance is very bad

Tags: java, mysql, database, prepared-statement

I have a for loop in order to add values to a PreparedStatement. The batch is just of 20k entries but its performance is poor.

At each iteration of the loop I do:
    statement.addBatch();

At the end I just do:
    statement.executeBatch();

Do I have to take something else into account? Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd better execute batch every 1000 or 5000 iterations

Comment: Define poor performance first plz.

Comment: @Antoniossss poor performance is 50s for every batch of 1000. Awful

Comment: so you got 1000 batches 20k queries each ?

Comment: @Antoniossss no. I have around 20k entries. With batches of 1k it is around 50s. So, 1000s for the 20k entries, 16 minutes in total.

Comment: Whats in prepared statement? Maybe query is poorly written? Maybe network latency? Did you try similar operations directly on database to see how long single op takes? Did you try to `explain` given query to see for any bottlenecks ?

Comment: @Antoniossss PreparedStatement pointDensityStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO point_density (id_place, algorithm, mission_date, mission_hour, x, y, times) VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); where is_place is int, algorithm is String, mission_date is java.sql.Date AND mission_hour, x, y and times are ints. Thanks for your attention!!!!

Comment: If some values are `null` you can try to use `preparedStatement.setNull(index, type)` instead of `preparedStatement.setXXX(index, value that is actually null);`

Comment: Ok so those are plain inserts which should be relativetly fast, maybe indeed network latency omes into play. Is that ran in the same machine as DB ?

Comment: @Antoniossss Latency is not the key I think... Could using a RDS MySQL micro instance be the bottleneck in batch inserting?

Comment: Could be. Those are shared instances.